# use getBaseline(int w, int h) of a child component in the parent container

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom swing component that has some child elements, including a JTextField. I want to give the container the same baseline as the JTextField, so I have overridden the getBaseline method in the container. But the position of the JTextField isn't always set when getBaseline is called for the container. I have tried to add a call to doLayout in the container's getBaseline method but that didn't help. What I want is the following:

```
public int getBaseline(int w, int h) {
    Dimension size = textField.getPreferredSize();
    int textBaseline = textField.getBaseline(size.width, size.height);
    int textY = textField.getY();
    return textY + textBaseline;
}
```

In the above code textY equals 0.

I've written some code to illustrate the problem. The first time "Add" is clicked the baseline is wrong. The second time it is correct.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class CustomComponent extends JPanel {

    public CustomComponent() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        textField.setColumns(8);
        layoutElements();
    }

    public void addComponent() {
        JPanel comp = new JPanel();
        comp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 200));
        comp.setBackground(Color.red);
        otherComponents.add(comp);
        layoutElements();
    }

    public int getBaseline(int w, int h) {
        Dimension size = textField.getPreferredSize();
        return textField.getY() + textField.getBaseline(size.width, size.height);
    }

    public Component.BaselineResizeBehavior getBaselineResizeBehavior() {
        return Component.BaselineResizeBehavior.CONSTANT_DESCENT;
    }

    private void layoutElements() {
        removeAll();
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        add(textField, constraints);

        for (JPanel comp : otherComponents)
            add(comp, new GridBagConstraints());
        if (getParent() != null)
            getParent().validate();
    }

    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private ArrayList<JPanel> otherComponents = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JButton addComponent = new JButton("Add");
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE;
        panel.add(addComponent, constraints);

        final CustomComponent customComp = new CustomComponent();
        panel.add(customComp, constraints);

        addComponent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                customComp.addComponent();
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that Components get added to the container at runtime. I also tried adding validate() to the getBaseline method and to the container's container after a new Component is added.

Comment: hmm ... can't reproduce in a quick test (simple JPanel returning the baseline of its first child) - best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial comment, just a confirmation:

Can confirm the problem with the outer layout either GridBag (your exact example) or MigLayout. Can hack around if the outer layout is FlowLayout. In that case forcing a layout before calculating the baseline is good enough

```
@Override
public int getBaseline(int w, int h) {
    // helps with simple managers like FlowLayout
    // detoriates with powerful managers like GridBag or Mig
    doLayout();
    Dimension size = textField.getPreferredSize();
    return textField.getY() + textField.getBaseline(size.width, size.height);
}
```

In the outer panel in main:

```
FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
flow.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
panel.setLayout(flow);
```

Not much, but maybe you can dig down a bit further from here ...

**Edit** Tentative solution (? or hack) and musings as to possible reasons

looks like it needs a forced two-pass layout process:

```
private void layoutElements() {
    removeAll();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    add(textField, constraints);

    for (JPanel comp : otherComponents)
        add(comp, new GridBagConstraints());
    if (getParent() != null) {
        getParent().validate();
        getParent().revalidate();
    }
}
```

Note the sequence of validate vs. revalidate - for some reasons, both are needed. No idea as to the exact mechanics, just random guessing:

- Layout happens top-down, so if the parent depends on the child having layed out all grandchildren would explain the need of the two-pass. A grand-child related baseline would be such a condition
- the first pass happens in a broader context, that is at the end of the first validate not all state is fully completed. Then a revalidate guarantees the second pass to happen *after* all the ongoing changes are completed.

Comment: Thanks, your second solution worked. I couldn't use FlowLayout in my project.

Comment: First trick worked for me. We use both GroupLayout and FlowLayout in different places and this seems to make it work for both.